# How to save all the rows of RadGrid at once into SQL Database on a button click along with another data which is outside of RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

There is a RadGrid (say "RadGridBill") in which I have 4 columns:

1. ID
2. Billing ID
3. Cost
4. Business Unit

Above RadGrid's (RadGridBill) data is bind using "Billing Table".

I have to show another RadGrid (say "RadGridInvoice") on web page,with below columns:

1. ID
2. InvoiceID
3. BillingID
4. Cost
5. Business Unit
6. Status
7. Invoice Number

There is a table named "Invoice Table" in database, with above columns.

There is a Button outside the RadGrid's named as "Generate" button.

**Now, my requirement is:** I have to save the records of "RadGridBill" using Billing Table (all rows) into database "Invoice Table" respective columns (i.e., Billing Table **Cost** column data should save in Invoice Table **Cost** column) along with the "Status"; on "Generate" button click

Also, the "Status" should be saved as "Draft" when user click on "Generate" button, into database "Invoice Table".

This all data has to save at once into the `Invoice` table.

Please let me know how to achieve above scenario.

I am very new to Telerik
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Telerik grids have different helper functions to save data. Please refer to their online help doc [Database Level Editing](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/database-level-editing). Also you should be able find detailed help for different data edit scenarios from the location.

Comment: As per my knowledge you have to manually  handle this thing in the C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Below code...

```
string InvoiceID;
string BillingID;
string Cost;
string BusinessUnit;
string Status;
string InvoiceNumber;
public static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString");
public SqlConnection SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
public SqlDataAdapter SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

public SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
private void insertgrd()
{
    foreach (GridDataItem itm in RadGrid1.Items) {
        InvoiceID = itm["InvoiceID"].Text;
        BillingID = itm["BillingID"].Text;
        Cost = itm["Cost"].Text;
        BusinessUnit = itm["BusinessUnit"].Text;
        Status = itm["Status"].Text;
        InvoiceNumber = itm["InvoiceNumber"].Text;
        try {
            //Open the SqlConnection
            SqlConnection.Open();
            //Update Query to insert into the database
            string insertQuery = "INSERT into Invoice values('" + InvoiceID + "','" + BillingID + "','" + Cost + "','" + BusinessUnit + "','" + Status + "','" + InvoiceNumber + "')";
            SqlCommand.CommandText = insertQuery;
            SqlCommand.Connection = SqlConnection;
            SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Close the SqlConnection


            SqlConnection.Close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Interaction.MsgBox("Unable to insert. Reason: " + ex.Message);

        }

    }
}
```

Call the above function in Button_click event...

Hope this Helps...

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Your code is working as per my requirement.